# Community Users have access to internal records?

Tags: permissions, sharing, lightning-community

For some unknown reasons, my org's Community Users have access to records that the internal org members generated. I have checked the following setting:

1. Opportunity Sharing Rule: none that applies to the specific role
2. Opportunity Access under Role: Users in this role cannot access
   opportunities that they do not own that are associated with accounts
   that they do own
3. Sharing Groups of each internal org member: There are no sharing
   groups established with Community Users

Does anyone have any idea as to what's going on?

Comment: What is the community license type? What is the Org-Wide Default on Opportunity? How are the users accessing the Opps - through native functionality or customization? If you click the Sharing button on some Opp that is visible, what rows do you see?

Comment: @DavidReed 
Community license type: Partner Community
Org-wide default on Opportunity: Internal - Private, External - Private, Grant Access using Hierachies
Users are access Opps thru Opportunity list view

Comment: @DavidReed
When I click the Sharing button, I see that: Owner has full access, Partner Manager has Read/Write Deal Access. The community user that is able to see internal org's records are not Partner Managers.